# During a Hibernate Cascaded save, how can we ensure a conditional update of inner objects

Tags: java, hibernate, conditional-statements, cascade

```
Consider the following class:
Class MainObject {
    ....
    ChildObject1 child1;
    ChildObject2 child2;
    ChildObject3 child3;
    ChildObject4 child4;
}
```

I need to save a newly created object of type MainObject using Hibernate. I added two newly created objects to it child1 and child2 since they were not present in DB. 
Let us say child3 and child4 were already present in DB. However I may not prefer to load the entire objects from DB and add them to the MainObject since those objects may have too many attributes, which are not needed.
So I just fetch the DB keys for the two objects and add the keys to newly instantiated ChildObject3 and ChildObject4 objects (which will have all other fields as null). I add these objects to MainObject.

Now, if I try to save MainObject in CASCADED mode, ChildObject3 and ChildObject4 will also get updated in DB with all null values, which I do not want. What I want is a way of cascading by which only non-persisted objects will be saved to DB (in this case ChildObject1 and ChildObject2). The other objects which hold a DB key will not be updated and will only serve to save MainObject.

I know cascading cannot function in this way. Is there any other way to do it such refresh the whole object hierarchy such that ChildObject3 and ChildObject4 get refreshed from DB and then I can save the MainObject in cascaded mode? Or can I put certain conditions in callout methods whether to update or not to update an object by checking if it holds a DB key or not?

I feel this is a needed operation. Whenever we save a new object, we may not always want to load all attributes of all the inner objects, just to be able to save the main object in cascaded mode. All we need is the DB primary key and may not prefer to stress the memory by loading all fields of all inner objects.

Any good solution or best practices, please suggest.

Comment: "So I just fetch the DB keys for the two objects and add the keys to newly instantiated ChildObject3 and ChildObject4 objects (which will have all other fields as null). I add these objects to MainObject." How would you do that? From the object view you work with Objects only - not keys. If you load the parent object lazily the children should not be loaded until you access them. The problem would not appear. If - for some reason - you do have the keys already you can create a proxy object manually with session.get()/entityManager.getReference().

Comment: Got the DB keys using sql queries since some of these objects have 25+ fields. The get function will have to be applied selectively to each persistent object (avoiding the non-persistent, new objects). Looking for a function that can be cascaded from top to bottom of the hierarchy (to be saved), which will refresh only persistent objects and ignore non-persistent ones, after which I can SAVE the hierarchy in one call.

Comment: If it is _only_ 25 fields, I would just fetch them eagerly. The number of columns you fetch has almost zero performance impact on the runtime of a query. Runtime is almost exclusively determined by the number of rows that have to be looked at to return the result.

Comment: I am mentioning about the load on RAM. Fetching many objects with so many fields may consume lot of space in RAM and if this is avoidable by fetching just DB keys, nothing like it.

Comment: I don’t know what you store in your fields but if each field is 10 bytes on average and you have 20 child objects than we are talking about 5kB. If you are concerned about that memory you should not use JPA because its footprint is huge in comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I do want to change the existing approach taken in the current project (by loading objects instead of DB key). Now I feel more confident that there is no harm in doing that. Thanks again for helping me take the better decision.